# Memory-efficient key-value store with duplicate keys

Tags: java, hashmap

I need something like this:

```
SomeMap someMap= new someArray;
someArray.put("color","red");
someArray.put("color","black");
someArray.put("brand","coca-cola")
someArray.put("brand","pepsi")
```

I don't care what the order is.
These are the methods I need:

Put key and value:

```
someArray.put("color","red");
```

Get by key:

```
someArray.get("color");
```

Get all:

```
someArray.getAll();
```

Remove all:

```
someArray.removeAll();
```

And I also need to be able to copy the structure:

```
someMap2 = someMap; (not shallow copy)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment?

Comment: Why don't you use a `HashMap`?

Comment: i tried to do but i always stuck with the part to copy this array without saving instance for him.

for example i have hashmap and i need to copy him to another hashmap

Comment: Do you know the difference between an `Array` and a `Map`?

Comment: yes,i read about that

Comment: So why does your question use SomeArray as the data structure? Array does not have a put method; it is not a key-value store.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by duplicate keys in the title?

Comment: you totally right. I change it now.

Comment: If you have duplicated keys your structure can not be a hashmap, unless you add the values as arrays. You need a List

Comment: change the type to Map<String, List<String>>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The part about allowing 'duplicate keys' in your question has me thinking what you really want is a [MultiMap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html), where a given key can map to more than one value.  Google has this in their [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) library - or you can roll your own with a `Map` whose values are a `List` implementation.  Here's an [example](https://dzone.com/articles/hashmap-%E2%80%93-single-key-and).

The declaration could be something like:

```
 Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>()
```

Comment: I tried to work with Guava but is too big library so i tried to find something else

Comment: OK, so roll your own, as I suggest in the second part of my answer.  I'll update to include an example.

Comment: i tried to do it but i have a problem when i need to copy this hashmap
something like that:
 Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>()


 Map<String, List<String>> mapCopy = new HashMap<String, List<String>>()

map = copyMap;

and any change i do in map change also the copyMap

how i can copy without to change him?

Comment: Huh?  What makes you think that declaring a new variable called mapCopy and initializing it is enough to copy the contents of the old map??

Comment: You need to write a method to copy the contents.  Why don't you wrap this thing in a class and write a copy constructor?

Comment: Have you maybe an example for me?

Comment: Here's an example of a copy constructor: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=12   Make an attempt and tell us where you get stuck.  I'm not going to put the two solutions together and solve your problem.

Comment: The part about Guava's library being too big sounds disingenuous to be honest.  Too big for what?

Comment: public void copyHashMap(Map<String, Set<String>> map) {
        Map<String, Set<String>> newMap = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
        newMap.putAll(map);
    }

Comment: when i put it on my project is required multiDex(65k)

Comment: i think Map<String, Set<String>> is better than Map<String, List<String>>,no?

Comment: OK - that's a fair point.  Now my suggestion is to read the Galaxy example I gave you, and write a copy constructor that loops through the entrys of the old map and deep copies them to the new map.  If the contents are just Strings, this should be fairly easy to do.

Comment: I do not find in this link something about deep copy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150487/discussion-between-yoni-and-amir-afghani).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have this without any external dependencies then the following code is all you need.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MultiValueMap {

    private static final Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        put("color", "red");
        put("color", "black");
        put("brand", "coca-cola");
        put("brand", "pepsi");

        System.out.println(get("color"));
        System.out.println(get("brand"));
    }

    public static List<String> get(String key) {
        return map.get(key);
    }

    public static void put(String key, String value) {
        if (map.get(key) == null) {
            map.put(key, new ArrayList<>());
        }
        map.get(key).add(value);
    }

}
```

Comment: In javax?  Not sure that's what he would want ....

Comment: you can simplify it to use only one `map.get(key)` operation